# How to Create Tabs in NextJS

Tags: tabs, graphql, next.js

I want to create tabs for categories. I get data categories with graphql and I want to display list data by the category selected.

tabs category

```
function a11yProps(index) {
  console.log(index);
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}
.....
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
......
{data.categories.map((category, i) => (
            <Tab
              key={category.id}
              label={category.name}
              id={`scrollable-prevent-tab-${category.id}`}
              aria-controls={`scrollable-prevent-tabpanel-${category.id}`}
              {...a11yProps(category.id)}
            />
          ))}
<ItemNews value={value} index={a11yProps()} />
```

ItemNews is component for display list data. And below some code for get list data

```
const { value, index } = props;
const { loading, error, data, refetch } = detailCategory({
    variables: {
      id: index,
    },
  });
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're facing?

Comment: my problem is I can't get detail id category, even all id category earned

Comment: query nothing wrong, my problem is when get id category @xadm

Comment: do you want to render tab contents with ItemNews ... place it inside map?

Comment: if inside in map, ItemNews looping too @xadm

Comment: ... each one with own id (for tabs hide/show), own `category.id` or `i` passed as `index`/whatever